# Mongoose cannot work with populate when trying to join two schema tables

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

**courseController.js**

```
const getCourses = async(req,res) => {
try{
    const courses = await Course.find({}).populate('user')
    res.status(200).json({success: true, message: "Success", data: courses})
} catch(err){
    console.log(err)
    res.status(404).json({success: false, message: "Failed to fetch courses"})
}   
}
```

**models/Courses.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const coursesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
title : {
    type : String,
    required : true,
    trim : true
},
description :{
    type : String,
    required : true,
    trim : true
},
image: {
    type : String,
    required : true
},
category : {
    type : String,
    required : true
},
price : {
    type : Number,
    required : true,
    trim : true
},
videos: [{
    type : mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref : 'videos'
}],
created_by : {
    type : mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref : 'user'
},
revenue : {
    type : Number,
    required : false,
    default : 0
}   
})

const Courses = mongoose.model('course', coursesSchema)

module.exports = Courses
```

**models/User.js**

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose')
const { hash, compare } = require('bcryptjs')

const userSchema = new Schema({
name : {
    type : String,
    required : true,
    trim : true,
    minlength : 3
},
email:{
    type : String,
    required : true,
    trim : true,
    unique : true,
    // validate : {
    //     validator : (data)=>{
    //         return validator.isEmail(data)
    //     },
    //     message : props => `${props.value} is not a valid mail id ` 
    // }
},
password : {
    type : String,
    // required : function(){
    //     return !this.isThirdPartyUser
    // },
    trim : true,
    minlength : 5
},
phoneNumber: {
    type: Number
},
role:{
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
},
courses : [{
    type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref : 'course'
}]
}, {timestamps : true })



const User = model('user', userSchema)
module.exports = User
```

**Courses.jsx**

```
{
                    courses && courses.map((course,index) => (
                        <div className="course-card" key={index}>
                            <img src={course.image} className="course-image" alt="" />
                            <h2 className="course-title">{course.title}</h2>
                            <p className="course-author">{course.created_by.name}</p>
                            <p className="course-rating">4.7 (2,770) reviews</p>
                            <h5 className="course-price">US${course.price} <del>US$299</del></h5>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
```

From the server side, I am trying to fetch all data of Courses table that can identify the name of `created_by` from the user table. When I try to get the data only the object ID could be shown instead of the name of user. Also, I try to use populate and it could not work with the function. May I ask any possible usage of `populate` when joining two tables?

Comment: What happens with `const courses = await Course.find({}).populate('created_by')`?

Comment: It works with this code